# Update varbinary(20) MySQL

Tags: mysql

гуру MySQL, подскажите, как правильно работать с типом данных varbinary(20)? Нужно взять исходное значение, изменить определенный бит и засетать обратно. 
Не получается последний этап, где строку конвертируем в varbinary(20). Тут явно обычным cast не поможешь.

```
 select  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3F0880FF; -- оригинал значения
   set @var = REPLACE('0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3F0880FF', '80', '81');
   select @var;  -- изменили бит и посмотрели 
   select  cast(@var as BINARY(20)); -- cast обратно и получили не 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3F0881FF, а 30784646....
```

Comment: *и получили не 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3F0881FF, а 30784646....* Что просил, то и получил - шестнадцатиричные коды символов строковой переменной.

Comment: А как получить назад вида 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3F0881FF?

Comment: У тебя даже тип данных в первой и второй строках кода разный... то есть в REPLACE отдаётся вовсе даже не "оригинал значения". Работай с бинарными данными, а не со строковыми. И функции/операторы используй соответствующие... если ты наивно полагаешь, что REPLACE в строковом литерале есть изменение заданного бита, то огорчу - это не так. . *А как получить назад вида* UNHEX().

Comment: Akina, спасибо, получилось!)